# PUZZLER: Around how many solar system bodies are there Legos in orbit?

Tags: orbit

I'll accept the largest defensible number.

**below:** "LEGO Building At KSC". Click image for full size - go ahead! From [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LEGO_Building_At_KSC.jpg).

[image]

Comment: Also answered on the LEGO Stackexchange: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/310/how-many-minifigs-have-actually-flown-in-space

Comment: @Raidri well it's a different but related question, and I'm surprised and happy to learn about another SE site with space-related questions!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Three Bodies**

1. **Earth**: Legos have made their way to the space station multiple times, and it doesn't appear as though they have left the station.
2. **Jupiter**: Lego figures were sent aboard the Juno spacecraft, and are currently orbiting Jupiter.
3. **Sun**: All legos in existence are currently orbiting the Sun, as both the Earth and Jupiter do :)

I do not believe they have ever orbited the moon, and I can't see any information for them being anywhere else in the solar system. [This](http://www.popsci.com/lego-figurines-on-juno-are-latest-in-long-line-bricks-in-space) is my source.

Comment: Ah, gotta make 'em harder! Sounds pretty good. Nice video here (skip the beginning though): http://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/space/go-for-launch/os-nasa-s-juno-spacecraft-buzzing-jupiter-s-great-red-spot-20170711-story.html

Comment: If the Sun counts, let's go with Saggitarius *, the supermassive black hole at the center of the Milky Way.

Comment: @jvriesem That is not a solar system body.  We hope.

Comment: Whoops! That'll teach me to read closely! :-)

Comment: I am not convinced that the figures sent on Juno are lego figures; considering that they are made from aluminium.

Comment: @Taemyr *who* made them out of aluminum?

Comment: You could add the Moon. The Moon and Earth (and all the Lego in existence except for what's on Juno) orbit a common point, the barycentre of the Earth-Moon system. You can just as well say the the Earth orbits the Moon as that the Moon orbits the Earth.

Comment: @uhoh I could be wrong but I Suspect that they where made by NASA.  I doubt LEGO would get the manufacturing capability to work with aluminium for a one off event.

Comment: @Taemyr I'd doubt even more that NASA would spend taxpayer dollars making LEGO figures! I'm pretty sure they were either mady by LEGO directly or LEGO subcontracted for it, but that's a guess. They both have access to cash but the private company would have much more flexibility for discretionary funds. Let's find out the facts!

Comment: @MikeScott I was considering putting that in, but I figured that doesn't really count as "orbit around". The barycentre is skewed too far towards the Earth, but you might be able to convince uhoh.

Comment: @MikeScott Since the Earth-Moon barycenter is well inside the Earth, it would be difficult to support the argument they're orbiting the Moon.  See also [this answer re. barycenter orbits](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14357/earth-moon-system-barycenter)